# React-Native update user name issue

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to get the username and profile picture from firebase-firestore. However when I update the state and try to type in a new value it keeps going back to the old value.

I am basically letting the user press edit profile and change their username. The current username is showing in the text field because of the `userName` state but it won't let me update it. It keeps reseting. I'm sure it is a small simple fix

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Input} from 'react-native-elements'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const EditProfile = () => {
    const [uid, setUId] = useState()
    const [userName, setName] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const profile = useSelector(state => state.User.uniqueId)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        getUserProfile()

    })

    const getUserProfile = async () => {
        setUId(profile)
        try {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('Users')
                .doc(uid)
                .onSnapshot(doc => {
                    setName(doc.data().fullName)
                })
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(true)
        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Input
                    label='Name'
                    value={userName}
                    onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default EditProfile
```

Please can you help me out. I'd really appreciate it. Thank you soo soo much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it fetch & update on every re-render:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        getUserProfile()

    })
```

If you only want this to happen on mount then provide an empty dep array:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        getUserProfile()

    }, [])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You're a genius!!!!! I also need help with adding to favourites but I haven't gotten any answers. If you don't mind please can you check this link. Thank you soo soo much in advance!!!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425143/react-native-add-to-saved-list